# Why is List<>.OrderBy LINQ faster than IComparable+List<>.Sort in Debug mode?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, benchmarking

I was interested in whether it would be faster to sort my classes using LINQ, or by implementing the IComparable interface and List.Sort. I was quite surprised when the LINQ code was faster.

To do the test, I made a very simple class with the not-so-apt name of TestSort, implementing IComparable.

```
class TestSort: IComparable<TestSort>  {
    private int age;
    private string givenName;

    public int Age {
        get {
            return age;
        }
        set {
            age = value;
        }
    }

    public string GivenName {
        get {
            return givenName;
        }
        set {
            givenName = value;
        }
    }

    public TestSort(int age, string name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.givenName = name;
    }

    public int CompareTo(TestSort other) {
        return this.age.CompareTo(other.age);
    }
}
```

Then a simple program to sort it many times - the sort was much more expensive than copying the list, so the effect of that can be ignored.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Create the test data
        string name = "Mr. Bob";

        Random r = new Random();
        var ts2 = new List<TestSort>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ts2.Add(new TestSort(r.Next(), name));
        }

        DateTime start, end;

        // Test List<>.Sort
        start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            var l = ts2.ToList();
            l.Sort();
        }
        end = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine("IComparable<T>: ");
        Console.WriteLine((end - start).TotalMilliseconds);


        // Test Linq OrderBy
        start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            var l = ts2.ToList();
            l = l.OrderBy(item => item.Age).ToList();
        }
        end = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine("\nLINQ: ");
        Console.WriteLine((end - start).TotalMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I was quite surprised to receive the following output:

```
IComparable<T>:
2965.1696

LINQ:
2181.1248
```

Sometimes LINQ would go below 2000, and sometimes IComparable would go about 3000.

When I tested it with a normal `List<Int>` the `List.Sort` was 1/4 the speed of LINQ, which remained at about 2000.

So why is LINQ only about 66% the speed of the normal sort for my class? Am I doing something wrong with my implementation of IComparable?

**Update:**
I just thought to try doing it in release mode, and yes, the results were different:

```
IComparable<T>:
1593.0911

Linq:
1958.1119
```

But I am still very interested to know why IComparable is slower in debug mode.

Comment: Did you try setting optimizations on in Debug mode (project properties) and seeing if its still slower ? If not, that may explain it.

Comment: Optimize Code is turned on... and I am looking for an actual reason rather than a contributing factor. I'm not trying to solve the problem, both methods are more than fast enough for my purposes, I just want to know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make sure everything is JITed before starting the measure, you might get different results. I also highly recommend using `BenchmarkDotNet` for microbenchmarks.

```
var ll = ts2.ToList();
ll.Sort();
ll.OrderBy(item => item.Age).ToList();
```

According to my measurements (after adding the above code), IComparable is always faster (even in debug).

Comment: How do you make sure that things are JITed before measuring?

Comment: Also. Doing the test up to about 900 times on my PC, the IComparable is faster. But if I loop more than 1000, then LINQ becomes faster. So there is some overhead on the initial LINQ setup, but repeated uses end up being faster.

Comment: In the code snippet, when you call `ll.OrderBy()`, the list has already been sorted on the previous line, so it is likely that there is less computation that has to occur when `OrderBy()` is called. Can you verify that in your stopwatch test, you are not calling `OrderBy()` on a list that was already sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Sort uses unoptimized quicksort, which has a n*n complexity in its worst case. I don't know what orderby uses but I know it doesn't use the same method since it's a stable sort, unlike `array.sort`.

Comment: Linq to objects OrderBy uses a stable quicksort, as opposed to Array.Sort which uses an unstable quicksort. There shouldn't be much difference in the speed cost of the algorithms.

Both of them are O(n log n).

Comment: Do you know if it is optimized or it is still with the same n^2 worst case?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I will use Linq with IComparable(when this is the most or only way to sort). In this case, item is a `TestSort: IComparable<TestSort>`

```
var sorted = ll.OrderBy(item => item); // This automatically used age to compare, as it's defined in CompareTo
```

`ll` can be any IEnumerable: List, Array, etc.

Also in `CompareTo` you can have multiple way to compare... for instance, you can do something like this:

```
  public int CompareTo(TestSort other) {
        return this.age != other.age ? this.age.CompareTo(other.age) : this.dateOfBirth.CompareTo(other.dateOfBirth);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could it be the overhead of calling the method `CompareTo` which would be replaced with an inline when compile and run in release mode.